# change colors of systemctl and journalctl output

Tags: systemd

Error messages are displayed dark red on black. I'm visually challanged and cannot read red text on a black background.

How can the colors of be adjusted in the output of `systemctl` and/or `journalctl` ?

Comment: To correct some of the colours you can try `export SYSTEMD_COLORS=0; export 
SYSTEMD_LOG_COLOR=0`. There are still some additional colours, but this is the best I found.

Comment: Rather than only adjusting the color scheme for a single application, consider making the color adjustments in your terminal. Then they’ll apply to all applications that color text. Applications display colored text (and other formatting options) by sending  ANSI escape sequences that get interpreted by your terminal and then your terminal adjusts the font and colors. Many terminals have an (often not immediately obvious) option to adjust/customize how each color instruction should get displayed. That should allow you to display ANSI red in a color that better suits your preferences.

Comment: my terminal is a fedora bash. how would I change the colors for all application. btw I'm not color blind and a white text on a red background is perfectly fine for me (and 25% of the male population dealing with the same challange)

Comment: To clarify: Most people work from a workstation with a GUI and and use a terminal emulator to get to a command line interface and/or to log in over for example ssh to remote systems. They for example use PuTTY when their desktop is Windows, iTerm2 when they’re on OSX or when they’re on Linux for their desktop, use kTerm, gnome-terminal etc etc , all of which can change how specific ANSI colors get displayed as far as I know. That way you don’t need to modify the remote servers, you don’t change anything for your colleagues, all adjustment is done locally for only  your terminal emulator.